# How to pretend a click on tabLayout in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

is it possible to perform a click on child on tanLayout with code not with "real action"?
Something like `tab[position].performClick()`? 
Does something like this exists?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select tab using below code:

```
 tabs.getTabAt(1)?.select()
```

Hope it will helps!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```
public static void onClickTab(TabLayout tab_layout) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tab_layout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildesCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildesCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Perfor your click acrtion
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using view pager with tab layout then simply use

```
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)
```

or if are not using viewpager then use

```
  mTabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
```